# Center an image inside div using formula

Tags: javascript, css

I am using a formula method to center the image inside the div.

Here is the link: http://fiddle.jshell.net/bPM73/10/

I don't know what is wrong in the formula, that image is not getting centered.
I mean I want both vertically and horizontally

Please help.

Comment: why not with just css `display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle`for wrapper

Answer (score 1):

you can made it only with css3 `box-align` property… working with all browsers (with prefix hack)

http://fiddle.jshell.net/bPM73/28/

Answer (score 0):

```
#i4 {
  display: block;
  width:300px;
  height:160px;
  top:0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  position:absolute;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Here is a trick. You can copy it into your fiddle and see it will works.

Comment: This is good, but here I want to get the center of the div so that I can scroll the image there.

Comment: Add new css rule to div `position: relavive;` @Archana

Answer (score 0):

I have edited the js and added position:relative to your wrapper div. check this out http://fiddle.jshell.net/bPM73/24/